# Predict MySQL errors when turning on STRICT mode(s)

Tags: mysql

I've got a database which hasn't been very well designed. For example, there are `DATETIME` fields (`not null`) which have values like `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

I want to turn on `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` mode. The database functions but the apps often fail with broken queries (often `INSERT`/`UDPATE`)

Are there any tools to recommend what should be fixed by looking at the data in tables & structure?

Specifically looking for:

- Built in warnings (if any?)
- Asking the mysql server if it thinks there is anything wrong with the structure & table data

Answer (score 0):

- There are few, if any, tools are available.
- You really must study the code enough to understand it, before thinking about automated fixes.
- You can probably study each problem in depth and fix it before moving on.  For example, changing 0 dates to NULLs is probably an ALTER plus an UPDATE.  But then the code needs changing to test for NULL instead of 0.